# Magento - Strange issue - Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i've created an extension.

Here is the error which i get from the system.log file:

```
2015-01-17T16:56:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: customer_id  in /home/sportsdi/public_html/beta/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/PercentShipping/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Discount.php on line 187
```

Here is the complete file: app/code/local/VivasIndustries/PercentShipping/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Discount.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_PercentShipping_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Discount extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{

     public function __construct()
    {
         $this -> setCode('discountshipping_total');
         }
    /**
     * Collect totals information about discount
     * 
     * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address 
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping 
     */

     public function getShippingPerc()
    {

        $EnableDiscountShipping = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/active');



        return ($EnableDiscountShipping==1);
    }


/*  public function SetPercSession(){

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcPayment('pc_payment');

    $PcPay = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcSession();

        if($PcPay == ""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcSession('no_redirect');
            header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
            exit;
        }

    }

    public function UnsPercSession(){
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPcPayment();
    $PcPay = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcSession();
        if($PcPay != ""){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPcSession();
            header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
            exit;

        }
    }   


    */

     public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
         parent :: collect($address);
         $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
         if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
         }
         $quote= $address->getQuote();

         Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));



         //amount definition


         if($this->getShippingPerc()) {

         $PcPayment = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcPayment();
         $PayOnDel = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPayOnDel();

         $Tax100 = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping100tax_percent');
         $Tax50 = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping50tax_percent');
         $Tax100ondel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping100ondeltax_percent');

         if($PcPayment==""){
         $discount = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping100_percent');
         }

         if($PcPayment!=""){
         $discount = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping50_percent');
         }

         if($PayOnDel!=""){
         $discount = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping100ondel_percent');
         }

         $totals = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());

         if($PcPayment!=""){
         $discountAmount = ($totals * $discount / 100);
         $discountAmount = $discountAmount*2;
         } else {
         $discountAmount = ($totals * $discount / 100);
         }


         //amount definition

         //Tax definitions
         if($PcPayment=="" && $PayOnDel==""){
             if($Tax100 >= $discountAmount){
             $discountAmount = $Tax100;
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);

             return $this;
             } else {
             $discountAmount = $quote -> getStore() -> roundPrice($discountAmount);
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);

             return $this;
             }

         }

         if($PcPayment!="" && $PayOnDel==""){
             if($Tax50 >= $discountAmount){
             $discountAmount = $Tax50;
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);

             return $this;
             } else {
             $discountAmount = $quote -> getStore() -> roundPrice($discountAmount);
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);

             return $this;
             }

         }

        if($PayOnDel!=""){
             if($Tax100ondel >= $discountAmount){
             $discountAmount = $Tax100ondel;
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);

             return $this;
             } else {
             $discountAmount = $quote -> getStore() -> roundPrice($discountAmount);
             $this -> _setAmount($discountAmount) -> _setBaseAmount($discountAmount);
             $address->setData('discountshipping_total',$discountAmount);

             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPercentShipping($discountAmount);


             return $this;
             }

         }       

         }

     }

     public static function getShippingPercent() {

     $ret = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPercentShipping();

     return $ret;
     }     

     public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {

         $EnableDiscount = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/active');
         $MinPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/percentpayment_min_amt');
         $MaxPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/percentpayment_max_amt');

         $SessionGrandTotal = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id)->getGrandTotal();


        if($this->getShippingPerc()) {
         parent :: fetch($address);
         $amount = $address -> getTotalAmount($this -> getCode());
         if ($amount != 0){
             $address -> addTotal(array(
                     'code' => $this -> getCode(),
                     'title' => $this -> getLabel(),
                     'value' => $amount
                    ));
         }

         return $address;
         }

     }

     public function getLabel()
    {
         $TaxLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentshipping/percentshipping_text');
         return Mage::helper('percentshipping')->__($TaxLabel);
    }

    /**
     * Get label
     * 
     * @return string 
     */

}
```

Can you please tell me how i can get more info about this error, why it comes and how i can fix it? How important is this error for the normal working of the extension and what kind of problem it may do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is enough explicit...
In the fetch method, you use a $customer_id variable, which is not defined...

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {

         $EnableDiscount = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/active');
         $MinPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/percentpayment_min_amt');
         $MaxPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/percentpayment/percentpayment_max_amt');

         $SessionGrandTotal = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id)->getGrandTotal(); // $customer_id is not defined.
```

Maybe you need to add $customer_id = $address->getCustomerId() ?

BTW your variables should be named $customerId by conventions ;)